# Accessing variable in inline expression (rmd to pdf output)

Tags: r, syntax, inline, markdown

I'm working on coding a reproducible rmd which will output a pdf document. I know that for an inline expression to work, it requires $ $ to be placed around it but is there a way around this?

`Client <- "Company X"`

`df <- data.frame(col1=c(1,1))`

Issue #1: Math mode formatting does not have spacing. Calling $`r Client`$ will output "*CompanyX*" and not "Company X"

Issue #2: I would also like to access values in dataframe, something like   $`r df$col1[1]`$. Escaping $ in the middle does not work either. I have also tried using `inline_expr()` in the `knitr` package.

Any tips would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: this seems to be just about R rather than the tex side of knitr, you might be better asking in an R forum, while it is technically on topic here most of us will have no idea how to help....

Comment: Imho the problem is not related with R at all, but with ignorance of what $....$ mean in LaTeX.  Inline R code *do not* need that. This simply put the R output in a LaTeX math environment, so in italic font and without spaces, exactly the same result that `$Company X$`. The solution  is as simple as just write ` r  Client ` , or, if you *really* need that string inside  a math formula,  use a latex command to left a nomal text inside that math environment, as `\mbox`,  or using the amstext  package,  `\text` or  `\textrm`  (e.g.:   $\mbox{` r Client  ` }$   ).